# serve nginx cached content to browser based on backend response

Tags: apache, nginx

Can I make request to tomcat or Apache server from Nginx, then after getting response from this request, i will decide either i have to serve from Nginx cache or forward to back end server(i.e Apache)

Answer (score 0):

Using proxy_cache_use_stale in your servers will help.
You can use it like this

`location / {
    ...
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
}`

read more [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html?&_ga=2.88379291.126288770.1496653126-1739642033.1496399261#proxy_cache_use_stale)

Comment: not the right solution for above problem. i have to make request to tomcat server per every request and based on this response i will decide to serve from cache or request to apache server.